# the possibility of creating a programming language without pointer aliasing

Tags: java, code-generation, parser-generator, compiler-construction

I have a question for all the programming enthusiasts out here. 
The pointers has always been there in the programming world. 
Like in C,C++ which has got a explicit pointer support.
In java explicit pointer support is not there, but internally the Java system uses pointers. 
Can there be a scope a programming language to be developed not to have pointer aliasing at all, in practical world?

Comment: You mean a language that has pointers, but no possibility of aliasing?

Comment: An implementation could prohibit referencing the same object in a variety of ways. You might be more interested in purely functional languages--but anything that refers to memory in any way, or keeps a program counter, will use pointers in its implementation.

Comment: You would need to implement this on a machine without the use of pointers. Since all CPUs I know use use them implicitly if not explicitly, this is unlikely. e.g. the program counter is a pointer.

Comment: See the `restrict` keyword in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Stack based languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language) are turing complete but have no pointers and no memory aliasing.

> A stack-oriented programming language is one that relies on a stack machine model for passing parameters. Several programming languages fit this description, notably Forth, RPL, PostScript, BibTeX style design language

If your stack based language allows you to interpret a value on the stack as a point on the stack, you could get problems similar to those introduced by pointer aliasing, but that need not be an allowable operation.

Comment: Forth doesn't have pointers in the same sense that assembly doesn't: it can treat plain integers as memory addresses.

Comment: Well... technically, Forth's `pick` will grab a value at an (essentially) arbitrary stack location, which is basically an indirect reference. (Besides `fill` and `erase`; don't recall if those are in the standard or an implementation detail.)

Comment: @sverre, good to know.  I was under the impression that PostScript did not, but am not confident of that.

Comment: well...i am developing a language which uses stack structure as well. But cant really feel that there can be languages which do not use pointers at all...anyways..what does this statement means? `If your stack based language allows you to interpret a value on the stack as a point on the stack, you could get problems similar to those introduced by pointer aliasing, but that need not be an allowable operation.
`

Comment: @mad_programmer, I meant the same thing that sverre meant about assembly languages and integers but he said it better.

Comment: Does it keep the calculating time not that bad? or it's just turing complete but slowing something a lot?

Comment: @l4m2 Since we're not talking about a specific language, it's hard to say anything about performance.  There's nothing about avoiding pointer aliasing that complicates performance though -- many common optimizations actually only work if there's no pointer aliasing: https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1307

Answer (score 4):

[Programming without Pointer Variables](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.7746&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describes using recursively defined data types instead of pointers in algorithms.

> The presence of pointer variables in high level
>   programming languages constitutes an artifact originally
>   introduced to support the representation of
>   recursive data structures.

Comment: This is a very interesting paper. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: The link is unfortunately broken, does someone have a mirror or a backup?

Answer (score 2):

If your language has arrays, and you can index those arrays with integer values, you have in effect aliasing within the array .

In general, this is true of any associative structures that maps a key to a value (arrays are a special case).  In effect, if your program is Turing capable and can generate keys, you can't prove generated keys don't "alias".

I think a language without some type of associative lookup is likely to be pretty useless in practice.

If you don't want to be bitten by this, you'll have to make your associative structures immutable.  In that case, you still have aliasing, but you can't be surprised by the value you fetch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate the problem of aliasing, I suggest you look into purely functional programming languages that prohibit mutating structures, such as Haskell, or languages where collections are copy-on-write, such as J.